# loop over array using charAt to get first letter of each value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, charat

I am new to JS and am trying to understand chartAt. I created a problem where I want to go through an array and pull the first character of each value from my array using charAt. I'm a bit stuck with my code.

```
var myArray = ['adam', 'bianca', 'cat', 'dennis'];
var myFunc = function (letter) {
    for (var i = 0; i < letter.length; i += 1) {
        letter.charAt(0);
        console.log(letter.charAt(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your iteration loop, `letter` is the array passed to the function `myFunc()`.  You need to access its elements, which you're iterating via `i`.  Use `letter[i].charAt(0)` instead of `letter.charAt(0)`

```
var myArray = ['adam', 'bianca', 'cat', 'dennis'];
var myFunc = function (letter) {
    for (var i = 0; i < letter.length; i += 1) {
        // Use the index i here
        console.log(letter[i].charAt(0));
    }
}

// Call your function, passing in the array you defined:
myFunc(myArray);
// a
// b
// c
// d
```

So your understanding of `String.prototype.charAt()` is correct, but the loop iteration was faulty.

Comment: What does .prototype mean? I am seeing that by others, but not clear on what it is and when I should use it.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain JavaScript object inheritance does not operate on classes like many other languages, rather prototype methods which are shared by all instances of an object type.

Comment: @jstone Some good stuff here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is go through each element in the array and get the first letter, you need to iterate over the *array*, not the word (which you call `letter` in your solution.  So you would have something like this:

```
for( var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++ ) {
    console.log( myArray[i].charAt(0) );
}
```

Or:

```
myArray.forEach( function(word){
    console.log( word.charAt(0) );
});
```

Also, you're creating a function (`myFunc`), but then you're never actually invoking it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems about right, except that you coded a constant in your loop instead of using the loop variable:

```
var myArray = ['adam', 'bianca', 'cat', 'dennis'];
var myFunc = function (letter) {
    for (var i = 0; i < letter.length; i += 1) {
        letter.charAt(i);
        console.log(letter.charAt(i));
    }
}


> myFunc(myArray[1])
b VM622:6
i VM622:6
a VM622:6
n VM622:6
c VM622:6
a VM622:6
undefined
```

You might also want to print out the whole array:

```
for (var word in myArray) {
    word = myArray[word];
    console.log("");
    myFunc(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you using jQuery

```
var myArray = ['adam', 'bianca', 'cat', 'dennis'];
$.each(myArray,function(){console.log(this.charAt(0))});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6

```
const myArray = ['adam', 'bianca', 'cat', 'dennis'];
myArray.forEach(myFunc => console.log(myFunc.charAt(0)));

//output
a
b
c
d
```

If you want to put the output in an array

```
const myArray = ['adam', 'bianca', 'cat', 'dennis'];
const myFunc = myArray.map(name => name.charAt(0));  

console.log(myFunc); 
//output
[ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
```

// When .map() is called on an array, it takes an argument of a callback function and returns a new array